# How to add in a new model item into an existing list without overriding the list?

Tags: flutter

I have this problem where the user input should be added into the answerlist. But after each input, the list seems to get override instead of add in new AnswerRequestModel item.

```
typedef void UpdateAnswerListCallback(
    List<AnswerRequestModel> updatedAnswerList);

class SubmitSurveyFormWidget extends BaseStatefulPage {
  SubmitSurveyFormWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.questionModel,
    required this.textEditingControllerMap,
    required this.onAnswerListChange,
  });

  final List<QuestionModel>? questionModel;
  final Map<int, TextEditingController> textEditingControllerMap;
  final UpdateAnswerListCallback onAnswerListChange;

  @override
  State<SubmitSurveyFormWidget> createState() => _SubmitSurveyFormWidgetState();
}

class _SubmitSurveyFormWidgetState extends State<SubmitSurveyFormWidget> {
  Map<int, TextEditingController> textEditingControllerMap = {};
  var textField = <AppTextFormField>[];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (var question in widget.questionModel ?? []) {
      if (question.questionType == SurveyQuestionType.TEXT) {
        int questionId = question.questionId ?? 0;
        widget.textEditingControllerMap[questionId] = TextEditingController();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
        ...(widget.questionModel?.map((question) {
              String questionNo = question.questionNo ?? '';
              String questionText = question.question ?? '';
              List<AnswerRequestModel> answerList = [];

              if (question.questionType == SurveyQuestionType.TEXT) {
                int questionId = question.questionId ?? 0;
                TextEditingController controller =
                    textEditingControllerMap[questionId] ??
                        TextEditingController();
                AnswerRequestModel newAnswer =
                    AnswerRequestModel(questionId: questionId);
                return Column(children: [
                  _buildQuestionForm(
                      questionNo: questionNo, question: questionText),
                  _buildTextFieldInput(
                      title: question.questionNo ?? '',
                      hintText: S.current.surveyFormMessage,
                      initialValue: controller.text,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          newAnswer = AnswerRequestModel(
                            questionId: question.questionId,
                            text: value,
                          );
                        });
                      },
                      onEditingComplete: () {
                        final questionId = question.questionId;
                        final textValue = controller.text;
                        final newAnswer = AnswerRequestModel(
                          questionId: questionId,
                          text: textValue,
                        );

                        answerList.removeWhere(
                            (answer) => answer.questionId == questionId);
                        answerList.add(newAnswer);

                        widget.onAnswerListChange(answerList);
                      },
                      textEditingController: controller),
                  SizedBoxGapConstant.gapH24,
                ]);
              } else if (question.questionType ==
                  SurveyQuestionType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {
                return Column(children: [
                  _buildQuestionForm(
                    questionNo: questionNo,
                    question: questionText,
                  ),
                  ...(question.choices?.map((choice) {
                        final splitChoiceList = choice.choiceValue?.split('\n');

                        List<Widget> choiceWidgets = [];
                        if (splitChoiceList != null) {
                          if (splitChoiceList.length > 1) {
                            choiceWidgets.add(RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: splitChoiceList[0],
                                  style: CustomStyles.surveyEngSelection),
                              const TextSpan(text: '\n'),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: splitChoiceList[1],
                                  style: CustomStyles.surveyBmSelection)
                            ])));
                          } else {
                            choiceWidgets.add(RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                text: splitChoiceList[0],
                                style: CustomStyles.surveyEngSelection,
                              )
                            ])));
                          }
                        }
                        return _buildMultipleSelection(
                          choice: choice,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            choice.isMySelection = value;

                            final questionId = question.questionId;
                            answerList.removeWhere(
                                (answer) => answer.questionId == questionId);

                            if (value == true) {
                              answerList.add(AnswerRequestModel(
                                questionId: questionId,
                                choiceId: choice.choiceId,
                              ));
                            }
                            widget.onAnswerListChange(answerList);
                          },
                          choiceWidgets: choiceWidgets,
                        );
                      }).toList() ??
                      []),
                  SizedBoxGapConstant.gapH20,
                  if (question.choices != null)
                    if (question.choices!.any((choice) =>
                        choice.childQuestions != null &&
                        choice.isMySelection == true))
                      SubmitSurveyFormWidget(
                        questionModel: question.choices
                            ?.where((choice) =>
                                choice.childQuestions != null &&
                                choice.isMySelection == true)
                            .expand((choice) => choice.childQuestions!)
                            .toList(),
                        textEditingControllerMap: textEditingControllerMap,
                        onAnswerListChange: widget.onAnswerListChange,
                      )
                ]);
              }

              return const SizedBox.shrink();
            }) ??
            [])
      ])),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextFieldInput({
    required String title,
    required String hintText,
    String? initialValue,
    required Function(String value) onChanged,
    required Function() onEditingComplete,
    required TextEditingController textEditingController,
  }) {
    FocusNode textFormFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();
    textFormFieldFocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!textFormFieldFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        onChanged(textEditingController.text);
      }
    });

    return AppTextFormField.survey(
      name: title,
      hintText: S.current.surveyFormMessage,
      hintStyle: CustomStyles.placeholderText,
      initialValue: initialValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        onChanged(value);
      },
      onEditingComplete: () {
        onEditingComplete();
      },
      focusNode: textFormFieldFocusNode,
      validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([]),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMultipleSelection({
    required ChoicesModel choice,
    required Function(bool? value) onChanged,
    required List<Widget> choiceWidgets,
  }) {
    FocusNode multipleChoiceFocusNode = FocusNode();
    multipleChoiceFocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!multipleChoiceFocusNode.hasFocus) {
        onChanged(choice.isMySelection);
      }
    });

    return Column(children: [
      Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                if (choice.isMySelection != null) {
                  onChanged(!choice.isMySelection!);
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: choice.isMySelection == true
                        ? CustomColors.borderInlineBlueColor
                        : CustomColors.primaryColor,
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 2,
                      color: choice.isMySelection == true
                          ? CustomColors.borderOutlineBlueColor
                          : CustomColors.lighterGreyColor,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                  ),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Column(
                        children: choiceWidgets,
                      )))))
    ]);
  }

  Widget _buildQuestionForm({String? questionNo, String? question}) {
    return Container(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border:
                Border(top: BorderSide(color: CustomColors.dividerLineColor))),
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: [
          Container(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 22, bottom: 12),
              child: Text('${S.current.questionTitle} $questionNo',
                  style: CustomStyles.getDirectionsText)),
          Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
              child: Text(question ?? '',
                  softWrap: true,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
          SizedBoxGapConstant.gapH12,
        ]));
  }
}
```

This is the widget page where the answerlist is processed. The processed answerlist(after all of the survey answer had inputted) will be pass back to the parent page.

```
class SubmitSurveyFormPage extends BaseStatefulPage {
  SubmitSurveyFormPage({super.key, required this.model, this.answerList});

  final SurveyModel? model;
  List<AnswerRequestModel>? answerList = [];

  @override
  State<SubmitSurveyFormPage> createState() => _SurveyQuestionTypeWidgetState();
}

class _SurveyQuestionTypeWidgetState extends State<SubmitSurveyFormPage> {
  final Map<int, TextEditingController> textEditingControllerMap = {};

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (var question in widget.model?.questions ?? []) {
      if (question.questionType == SurveyQuestionType.TEXT) {
        int questionId = question.questionId ?? 0;
        textEditingControllerMap[questionId] = TextEditingController();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final questionModel = widget.model?.questions ?? [];
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: _submitButton(),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          SurveyItemDetailCard(widget.model),
                          SubmitSurveyFormWidget(
                            questionModel: questionModel,
                            textEditingControllerMap: textEditingControllerMap,
                            onAnswerListChange: (updatedAnswerList) {
                              setState(() {
                                widget.answerList = updatedAnswerList;
                              });
                            },
                          )
                        ]))))));
  }

  Widget _submitButton() {
    return BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: ButtonWidget.filledButton(
              backgroundColor: CustomColors.torchRedColor,
              btnText: S.current.submit.toUpperCase(),
              onPressed: () {
                submitSurvey();
              },
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            )));
  }

  Future<void> submitSurvey() async {
    final int? surveyId = widget.model?.surveyId;
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    if (surveyId != null) {
      final bool success = await context
          .read<SurveyViewModel>()
          .postSurveyAnswer(
            SurveyAnswerModel(surveyId: surveyId, answers: widget.answerList),
          );

      if (success) {
        context.push(NavigatePath.submitSurveySuccess);
      }
    } else {
      context.pop();
    }
  }
}
```

I have try to make the form key in the parent page and try to use onEditingComplete in the textfield but nothing seems to work. What should I do?

The expected list should be:

```
answerlist: [Instance of AnswerRequestModel, Instance of AnswerRequestModel, ...]
```

Instead I have now:

```
answerList: [Instance of AnswerRequestModel]
```

The output of the answerlist now is the last input of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (question.choices != null)
                if (question.choices!.any((choice) =>
                    choice.childQuestions != null &&
                    choice.isMySelection == true))
                  SubmitSurveyFormWidget(
                    questionModel: question.choices
                        ?.where((choice) =>
                            choice.childQuestions != null &&
                            choice.isMySelection == true)
                        .expand((choice) => choice.childQuestions!)
                        .toList(),
                    textEditingControllerMap: textEditingControllerMap,
                    onAnswerListChange: widget.onAnswerListChange,// this is not updating I think,
                  )
```

You need to call `widget.onAnswerListChange(answerList)`

```
onAnswerListChange: (){
widget.onAnswerListChange(answerList);}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But now I have a new problem where the subquestion answerList cannot be pass to the form page.